# Objective C locations of character in string

Tags: objective-c, string, character, range

I have a question about the rangeOfString method. For example:

```
string = @"abcagha";
int e = [string rangeOfString: @"a"].location;
```

This return only the first occurrence (e = 0), how do I get all of them (0,3,6)?

Comment: Side note - you need to make `e` an `NSUInteger`, not `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop and `rangeOfString:options:range:`. Each time you go through the loop, adjust the range to start beyond the location of the previous match.

Another option is to use `NSRegularExpression` and the `matchesInString:options:range:` method.

```
NSString *string = @"abcagha";
NSRegularExpression *exp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"a" options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [exp matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
NSMutableArray *locations = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    [locations addObject:@(match.range.location)];
}

NSLog(@"\"a\" was found in \"%@\" at: %@", string, locations);
```